# Get Mac logged in user email in Electron Application

Tags: javascript, macos, desktop-application, electron

In Atom Electron desktop application, is there any way to get the logged in user's email address in Mac OS X, So that I can use that email address in the `main js` file

I have searched in stackoverflow and other resources, but didn't find a way to do that.

Comment: is it anyway related to coding?